# Circular Longest Increasing Subsequence

Tags: algorithm, lis

How can I find the length of Longest Increasing Sub-sequence if the numbers are arranged in circular fashion. For example:

`LIS of 3, 2, 1 is 3 [1, 2, 3].`

P.S I know how to solve Linear LIS in O(nlogn).

Problem Source: https://www.codechef.com/problems/D2/

Update: The LIS has to be calculated by going through the circle only once. 
Example 2: `LIS of 1, 4, 3` is 2 and that could be either of `1, 3`  or `1, 4` or `3, 4`.
Thanks

Comment: Is this a homework assignment?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Of course not..!! What made you think so? I was learning DP from this source https://www.codechef.com/wiki/tutorial-dynamic-programming and this problem was mentioned as a practice problem in the tutorial.

Comment: @user3518014 what would be the output of this **input:** `4, 1, 2, 2, 3`. will it be `4` or `5` ?

Comment: 4 formed by:  `1, 2, 3, 4`

Comment: You could apply `LIS` to every rotation of the array. Would be `O(n^2 log n)`.

Comment: @IVlad Yes. But i am looking for a O(nlogn) or O(n^2) solution.

Comment: I don't understand the example given in the question, you can't shift [1,2,3] to get [3,2,1] as a subsequence.

Comment: shifting gives 3 1 2  . It doesn't give 3 2 1

Answer (score 0):

The example in question is wrong. circular rotation of [1,2,3] would be [2,3,1] or [3,1,2].

In which case, we can solve it similar way as longest increasing subsequence. As:

1. Sort the list in ascending order.
2. Find min element in the original list.
3. Start iteration from min_index in original list and compare it with sorted list, and create intermediate array L[i][j] with same logic as longest common subsequence. i will vary from min_index to (i+n-1)%n
4. Finally return L[max_index][n]